# JMeter Regular Expression to retrieve multi-line records

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

```
{
    "GROUP1": {
        "USER1": {
            "name": {
                "title": "Mr",
                "surname": "David",
                "firstname": "Morgan",
                "othernames": "Joseph"
            },
            "dateofbirth": {
                "year": "1934",
                "month": "12",
                "day": "28"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone share what the JMeter Regular Expression is to retrieve everthing between {} after **"name":** please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use instead JSON path extractor or JSR223 PostProcessor (or more) see [example](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

Parsing [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) using Regular Expressions is not the best idea, starting from [JMeter version 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you have [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) queries against JSON responses.

In particular your case the relevant JSON Path query should look like:

```
$..name
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSONPath]